# How does web-player cache works?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

I am having issue when caching a web-player whereby my browser unable to cache my web-player application. My web-player application size is 35Mb.I have searched in google and one link says like this: The browser will cache what it considers acceptable. if your player etc is always below 5mb most browsers should cache it, above ... well not so much.Firstly help me is it possible to cache a 35MB web-player application.If possible could you please provide me the answer.

Comment: Web Player has been disconnected about over a year ago. Answering this would be west of your time!

Comment: Look Into signal R, if your game is 2D. I have seen a youtube video recently that makes an attempt at web.